# Magnific Popup with partial path url not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, magnific-popup

This is an AngularJS app and I have jQuery and the required .js files as this works with some code copied and pasted from the magnific popup website/documentation.
The code below is the magnific popup code in the AngularJS controller, yes it works fine on the image that is pasted from the documentation.

I'm guessing the issue is with the values of my href attributes being href='../uploads/image.jpg' and not a full URL.

I didn't find any mention of needing a full URL in the href attributes but I might have overlooked it. Below is the image from the magnific site and directly below the generated HTML (using Chrome dev tools to inspect) is the image with ng-src attribute and an href with the path.

```
      //Magnific-popup
$('.single-popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'mfp-with-fade',
    closeOnContentClick: true
});





    <a class="single-popup"
  href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg">
                        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" width="107" height="75">
                    </a>


   <a class="single-popup" href="../uploads/id70.jpg" title="bradmartin's Profile Pic">
   <img ng-show="u.ImagePath != null" ng-="" src="../uploads/id70.jpg" width="50" height="50">
                            </a>
```

The SOURCE CODE:

```
                        <tr ng-repeat="u in Users" ng-style="{'color': (u.Status == false ? 'red' : '')}">
                            <td>
                                <img ng-show="u.ImagePath == null || u.ImagePath == 'null'" src="../images/avatar.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
                                <a class="single-popup" href="{{u.ImagePath}}" title="{{u.Username}}'s Profile Pic">
                                    <img ng-show="u.ImagePath != null" ng- src="{{u.ImagePath}}" width="50" height="50" />
                                </a>
```

Comment: I've messed around with the code some more to determine the issue. It is not the databinding or the path. It seems to be more of an issue that the code resides within an AngularJS ng-repeat.

Comment: I don't have the time to investigate this much further but it's definitely the fact it's within the ng-repeat. I've tried different elements (to be certain) and it didn't work within a <ul> or <table>. I've also removed the ng-show directives and it's still the same result. The images in ng-repeat don't work and those outside work fine, even when their href and src values are databinded {{}}.